# Generate Excel file to .txt file and do some looping

Tags: vba, excel, notepad

I want to generate excel file to .txt file and do some looping.
For example like this:

In Excel:

```
A | B | C | D
--+---+---+---
1 | 5 | 9 | 1
A | H | U | I
```

Will be generate to .txt like this:

```
"A", "1"
"B", "5"
"C", "9"
"D", "1"
"A", "A"
"B", "H"
"C", "U"
"D", "I"
```

Edited:
This is my coding

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sFirst As String
Dim sSecond As String
Dim sThird As String
Dim sFourth As String
Dim sFName As String
Dim intFNumber As Integer
Dim lHeader As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long
Sheet1.Activate
Range("A1").Select
With Sheet1
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

sFName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Date" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".xls"

'Get an unused file number
intFNumber = FreeFile

'Create a new file (or overwrite an existing one)
Open sFName For Output As #intFNumber

For lHeader = 1 To lLastRow
    With Sheet1
        'For header
        sFirst = .Cells(lHeader, 1)
        sSecond = .Cells(lHeader, 2)
        sThird = .Cells(lHeader, 3)
        sFourth = .Cells(lHeader, 4)
    End With

    'Write selected data to text file
    Write #intFNumber, sFirst, sSecond , sThird, sFourth
Next lHeader
Close #intFNumber

MsgBox "Values from sheet '" & Sheet1.Name & "' were written to '" & sFName & "' file!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

But it only generate like this:

```
"A", "1"

"B", "5"

"C", "9"

"D", "1"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have but it only generate this: I want to generate excel file to .txt file and do some looping. For example like this:
"A", "1"
"B", "5"
"C", "9"
"D", "1"
@Cleb

Comment: @bonCodigo I have updated my Question with some coding..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'Write selected data to text file
Write #intFNumber, "A", sFirst
Write #intFNumber, "B", sSecond
Write #intFNumber, "C", sThird
Write #intFNumber, "D", sFourth
```

instead of this:

```
Write #intFNumber, sFirst, sSecond , sThird, sFourth
```

Comment: thank you so much..now it can displayed as per expected.. @shA.t

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 Write #intFNumber, sFirst, sSecond , sThird, sFourth
```

with

```
Print #intFNumber, sFirst , sSecond , sThird, sFourth & Chr(10)
```

To add new lines add `& Chr(10)` or `& vbNewLine`

Comment: Writing goes by row. While using print, you may want to add the delimiters and quotations that you need. `Print` doesn't add those unlike `Write`.

Comment: I have tried it but it's not as what as expected. After change Write to Print: 
"A", "1","A" 
"B", "5","H" 
"C", "9","U" 
"D", "1","I"

Comment: See updated post - I thought you want to drop the quotation marks? Add `Chr(10)` or `Chr(13)` or `vbNewLine` to add new line

Comment: @AnalystCave.com can you please explain it more to me about the vbNewLine. I'm sorry, I'm quite new to VBA Macro.

Comment: `vbNewLine` is a character representing a new line in VBA. E.g. str = "Hello" & vbNewLine & "John" will generate a string with Hello in the first row and John in the second